# MVVMCross core (PCL) projects consumed as Nuget package

Tags: mvvmcross, nuget-package

I have not tried it myself but wanted to see if someone has already explored this scenario?

Will MVVMCross be able to detect/link View-ViewModels etc. and work just as is if:

I have an X.Droid and X.iOS project along with a shared core PCL project in Solution A.
I want to write ViewModel classes in additional/separate core (PCL) projects, added in Solution B, have a nuget package as output and then consume/reference/add package in the Droid and iOS projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override your `Setup.cs` class to provide more assemblies in where MvvmCross should look for ViewModels.

So if you are writing most of your app in assembly A, but have some shared ViewModels in assembly B and maybe some in assemby C, you would do something like this:

```cs
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> GetViewModelAssemblies()
{
    var vmAssemblies = new List<Assembly>(base.GetViewModelAssemblies())
    {
        typeof(ViewModelInAssemblyB).Assembly,
        typeof(ViewModelInAssemblyC).Assembly
    };
    return vmAssemblies;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I did not get to the stage where I had to try your suggested solution, I simply added the nuget packages to the droid and ios apps and it worked like charm. I will still accept your answer since it provides another way of implementation.